# MapKit IOS Not Centering on Pin

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm having an issue with my MapKit not centering on my pin that I have set. Instead it is loading like [this.](http://i.imgur.com/HkM7TRg.jpg?1)

I've tried multiple different things, for example could the issue be related to the MapKit properties in the storyboard? Maybe but I don't think so. I also can't seem to find much on the web relating to this issue? Here is my code that I believe might be relevant:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Foundation
class First: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        var location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-37.81411, 144.96328)

        var span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)

        var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)


        Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)


        var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = "Pizza Pistorante"
        annotation.subtitle = "Luna Rossa"

        // Add annotation to the scene

        Map.addAnnotation(annotation)



    }
}
```

Comment: Do you set constraint for your mapView?

Comment: No, would setting a constraint help?

Comment: Yes because  I test your code and it is working fine and I have added constraints.

Comment: That fixed it, such a simple thing that I needed to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add constraint to your mapView this way:

Select your mapView from storyBoard then go to Pin Menu and add this four constraint as shown in below image:

[image]

And your map annotation will display at center.